# What is preferredheapbase parameter in websphere?

Tags: tomcat, websphere

Does anyone knows what is preferredheapbase parameter in websphere used for?
Is there any similar parameter for tomcat ?

Something I could find from the [IBM Website](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21660890).

```
-Xgc:preferredHeapBase=0x100000000
```

This will locate the Java heap starting at the 4GB mark thus leaving the lower 4GB for the other processes.

Can we set this parameter in tomcat?

Answer (score 2):

This is not an application server setting, it's an IBM JVM setting. It has the same effect on any process running on an IBM JVM, including tomcat.

As far as the use, it is apparently important for some non java-heap allocations to have addresses below the 32-bit line. By putting the java heap higher, it allows those later allocations to occur under the 32-bit line.  The memory used by thread creation is one example.

The downside of creating the entire heap above the 32-bit line is that the "compressed references" feature of the IBM 64-bit JVM is not as efficient.

Answer (score 0):

In IBM 64-bit JVM, a concept is used called compressedrefs while using a heap size <25GB. The reason is:

1. 64bit JVM will use 64bit objects, thus increasing object size and access time, especially if the application is not 64-bit optimized.
2. To improve performance and reduce memory footprint, compressedrefs places classes, threads and monitors under 4GB (32-bit) memory line.
3. If the java heap size is set as less than 4 GB, the heap maybe placed below this 4GB mark
4. Additionally, the operating system uses this address space for own perpose, and stores some native libraries as well.

This setup helps to improve JVM performance in terms of memory footprint and memory access time. However, this has a drawback. As the under 4GB memory gets filled with Java heap, classes-threads-monitors, and OS libs, if the 4GB memory is exhausted and the heap cannot grow any further, JVM will throw a ntive out of memory exception while trying to allocate memory for an object.

To mitigate this issue, -Xgc:preferredHeapBase=0x100000000 option is used. This instructs the JVM to begin heap base at 0x100000000 (4GB) - and heap grows from 4GB memory mark and above. This provides enough space for the heap to grow. Classes, threads and monitors are still place below 4 GB, thus they can still leverage the performance improvement of using compressedrefs.

You may refer to this document for detailed description on compressedrefs implementation:

ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/webserver/appserv/was/WAS_V7_64-bit_performance.pdf

This is a JVM specific option and can be set for any application running on the JVM.